# How do cars move, it seems inexplicable (to me)?

Tags: energy, machine-elements, fuel

*Confiteor*, I have only a rudimentary knowledge of how machines work. I'll be discussing fossil fuel engines only.

First off, I have a block of iron, B. I find a pan balance. I place B in one of the pans. I then place X in the other pan. X > B. The arms will move in such a way that you can infer, *B can't lift X*. Now remove X, place Y in its place. Y = B. Equilibrium!!!

Conclusion: If X > B then B can't lift X (we're talking about *weight* here).

My question is, with a car, the weight of the fuel (even at full tank) is much, much, less than the weight of the car + fuel. and yet ... a fraction of the fuel "lifts" the car.

*Quomodo*?

Comment: Is this the car in Harry Potter?

Comment:  *Je ne sais pas*. Are we in Hogwarts ...School of Magic?

Comment: By this logic, do you have to eat food that weighs more than you in order to walk?

Comment: maybe your thoughts are clouded by some preconceived notions ... consider this ... if the car is on level ground then you can probably push it and it will roll ... do you weigh more than the car?

Comment: If the car is lifted off the ground, where does the force to provide forward, or reverse, motion come from - since it cannot be friction between the tire and the ground anymore.

Comment: Do you know how a simpler engine works? For example compressed air powered piston engine? Or how "wind up" spring powered toy car works?

Comment: Your lifting scenario is deceiving. It isn't that difficult to lift something when you do not specify how quickly, or how far you need to lift it. You also can't really get a feel for how much energy 1L of gasoline contains because something like that just isn't part of human experience. Think about how far you have to run to burn off a hamburger or piece of cake.

Comment: You are trying to equate a simple machine to a complex machine.  The engine does not lift the car.  It's not a rocket motor.  It uses gearing to spin wheels.  You need to clarify your question.  Start with *a fraction of the fuel "lifts" the car.*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the gasoline contains a tremendous amount of stored *chemical energy* per pound of weight. the engine in the car burns the gasoline to release the stored chemical  energy as heat and convert that into shaft work, which turns the wheels of the car.

Comment: Suppose a simple gasoline engine + its fuel tank. There's $1$ L of fuel in it only. It burns that $1$ L and since "gasoline contains a tremendous amount of stored *chemical energy* per pound of weight", it produces enough energy to *lift* the engine cum the fuel tank with the fuel off the ground. *Gracias*

Comment: A full gas tank in a typical car contains roughly the same amount of stored energy as a full box of dynamite sticks. The gasoline  reacts much more slowly than the dynamite.